# Continuously update element on scroll using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a h2 HTML element that displays the position of a div when a user scrolls down on the webpage. I want this h2 element to update the position of the div past the initial scroll, so that when I keep scrolling down, the number that displays the y-coordinate of the element descending. Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adnLX/

Script I'm using to display the position:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $(window).scroll(function(){
    var xx = $("#bottom").position().top;

     $("#title").html(xx);
 });
 });
```

To recap, I want to continuously update and display the position of a div (it's represented by the "0" on the bottom of the first page) as it is scrolled up and down, but so far, I can only display the initial position when I first scroll. How do I revise my script to continuously display the position?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look at `scrollTop`.  The position of `#bottom` doesn't change so that `.top` call will never change.

But the scroll position will change.  Try something like this

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var xx = $("#bottom").position().top;
    var bottomPosition = $('body').scrollTop() - xx;
    $("#title").html(bottomPosition);
 });
```

I tried this in your fiddle and it seemed like it might be doing the right thing.